# want to pick a random number from an array list

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

Have to pick a random number from an arraylist, to generate proper information from a database, its bugging on the rnd line at this moment

```
    Dim rn As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim QPass As String
    rn.Add(71)
    rn.Add(72)
    rn.Add(79)
    rn.Add(80)
    Dim index As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(Rnd() * 4))
    Dim randomValue As Integer = CInt(rn(index))
    QPass = randomValue.ToString()
    Session("Pt2") = rn
    PT2imgImage.ImageUrl = "showImage.ashx?i=" + QPass
    PT2imgImage.Width = Unit.Pixel(600)
```

Comment: Your assigning an integer to an arraylist variable

Comment: Use the `Random` class instead.  `Rnd` is an old VB6 function provided for backwards compatibility.

Comment: FYI, `ArrayList` is deprecated, use the generic container `List(Of T)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
rn = rn(Rnd() * 4)
```

you are trying to put an Integer (the value selected from the ArrayList), into a variable declared as ArrayList. That won't work. Use a new variable:

```
Dim index As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(Rnd() * 4))
Dim randomValue As Integer = CInt(rn(index))

QPass = randomValue.ToString()
Session("Pt2") = randomValue
```

`CInt(Math.Floor(...))` ensures that the floating point value returned from `Rnd() * 4` is correctly rounded down and converted into an integer, which can then be used to index an array list. Eventually, you might want to replace this by a more .NET way to get a random number (e.g. [`Random.Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx)). `Rnd` is mainly for backwards compatibility.

The `CInt` around `rn(index)` is required, since you use an old, untyped `ArrayList` instead of a new, shiny, strongly-typed `List(Of Integer)`. If you use the latter, you can remove the outer `CInt`.

Comment: thank you this has been very insightful, this community has helped me develope my programming skills tremendously, hopefully soon ill be on the answer side of the questions. Cheers!

Comment: for some reason this is only returning 79

Answer (score 2):

```
    Dim rn As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim QPass As String
    Dim rnd As New Random
    rn.Add(7)
    rn.Add(8)
    rn.Add(15)
    rn.Add(16)
    Dim randomValue As Integer = rn(Rnd.Next(0, 4))
    QPass = randomValue.ToString()
```

thought i would work with the newer style as suggested